# How can I troubleshoot MTP on my Galaxy Nexus

Tags: usb-connection-mode, shell, mtp

My Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2 won't show up as a MTP device anymore. It looks like the phone is the problem, I want to debug the problem from that end.

Like [many before me](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35635/12736), I tried everything, and then some :

- Using Ubuntu 13.04 or Windows 7, on 3 computers
- Cleaning the USB port on the phone
- Using the original cables
- Reboot with or without the cable, with or without the SIM card
- Removing the battery all night (after shutting down the phone) to clear *everything* from memory
- Uninstalling Google Play Music (I only use MTP to sync music)

I also have a second phone that shows up as a MTP device and syncs just fine. It is also a Galaxy Nexus running 4.2.2. Neither of them are rooted. So I think the phone must be the problem.

How can I troubleshoot or debug MTP problems **on the phone** ?

Comment: I see the `/dev/mtp_usb` kernel driver, which led me to [this patch](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/27bd34d9d9fe99f11b80aa0bbdb402fb47ef4158%5E!/). But how do I know if the mtp_usb driver is working on the device ?